# Synonyms for "healthy" in "healthy foods"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In the editorial I am writing, I repeatedly say "healthy foods". I searched healthy up in a thesaurus so my paper would not sound so repetitive. The results were ones such as

> > fit, active, lively, robust, strong, etc.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/healthy

I am not looking for "healthy" that means athletic or fit, I am looking for healthy that means good for you.

The sentence in which "healthy foods" is used is

> > Eating healthy foods and drinking water five to seven times in a day is essential to an active brain and body.

Comment: First you need to come up with a definition of "healthy foods".  High carb, low carb, vegan, ad nauseam.

Comment: @HotLicks In my essay, I use healthy foods. I am saying foods that are good for health, not defining what makes them good for health. If I had to define them, I would say they are from all over the food triangle. A healthy balance of foods.

Comment: If you're trying to be generic you probably should say "healthy diet" rather than "healthy foods".  Then you can play with "well-balanced" and probably one or two other idiomatic terms.

Comment: Try looking for synonyms of ***nutritious*** rather than healthy.

Comment: If you go to page 2 of your link, you'll find relevant synonyms.

Comment: Could be just the pedant in me, but I would never say "healthy food" when what I meant was "healthful". The food, after all, isn't usually what's healthy.

Comment: @1006a Nutritious... why did I not think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Try looking up healthful instead of healthy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might say **nutritional foods**, according to the BBC:

> "The key is to eat a balance of highly **nutritional foods**, that when consumed together, do not contain too much of any one nutrient, to avoid exceeding daily recommended amounts." [1](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20180126-the-100-most-nutritious-foods)

You could also speak of **nutritious foods**, from the same article:

> "Calculated and ranked by scientists, these are the 100 most **nutritious foods**:"[1](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20180126-the-100-most-nutritious-foods)

#### Attribution

"Future - The World's Most Nutritious Foods." BBC. January 29, 2018. Accessed March 21, 2018. http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20180126-the-100-most-nutritious-foods.

Comment: I suspect "nutritious" ([containing the substances needed for life](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nutritious)) is closer to the desired meaning than "nutritional" ([related to food/nutrition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nutritional)) in most contexts.

Comment: @psmears I've read the article I link to in my answer again, they seem to use both. They speak of "nutritional score" as well as "nutritional foods". They also use nutritious to say a particular food is nutritious. I will add it in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

**wholesome**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wholesome)

**conducive to or characteristic of physical or moral well-being**

Synonyms of wholesome foods (my summary - see link for full text):

> ```
> healthful
> healthy
> sound
> financially secure and safe
> alimental, alimentary, nourishing, nutrient, nutritious, nutritive
> heart-healthy
> good for you, healthy, salubrious
> hearty, satisfying, solid, square, substantial
> providing abundant nourishment
> organic ... foodstuffs w/o synthetic fert/pesticides/hormones
> salubrious
> ```

Comment: All good ones. Except for 'salubrious'. Sure it has the right meaning but...just no.

Comment: @Mitch that was vocabulary.com lol

Comment: 'Organic' also seems to say more about the type of food than just 'healthy'.  Food can be considered healthy even when it's not organic, and organic food can be as unhealthy as food can be (think of sugar, that's organic too ;) )

Comment: When word nerds form gangs, an initiation rite will be, for the first person they come across that uses 'salubrious', to flip the Scrabble board.

Comment: @JJJ   lol, just citing vocabulary.com.  And I like salubrious - to body and mind!

Comment: Haha...no need to remove 'salubrious', I was just commenting on its...weird-soundingness, purple-proseishness. Removing it makes me ... lugubrious.

Comment: @Mitch  I am just a low rep sycophant ... editing when  a 45K member comments! lol

Comment: ... because flipping the Scrabble board is ... execrable.

Comment: @Mitch why no salubrious?

Comment: This conversation is so ... *jejune*.

Comment: @Ooker pardon me for being contumelious, or is it contumacious", but 'salubrious' sounds nothing like what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: such a wholesome and healthful conservation going on here in comments

Comment: @Mitch why not? I see [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=salubrious&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi43LPo-v7ZAhUPhrwKHfIoA6IQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=660) kind of agree that salubrious can go with food

Comment: @Ooker Don't be ludibrious. I'll acquiesce to a sagacious kombucha before regaled with a repast of salubrious legumes.

Comment: @Ooker kombucha!? should i add that as a synonym?

Comment: @lbf Kombucha is a health food, but not a synonym of healthy foods in general. I should know because my mom has a kombucha every night.

Comment: @Mitch I was never comfortable using 'salubrious' because it sounded so ... so. Once I learnt _saludable_ (healthy/wholesome) in Spanish,  'salubrious' seemed like a word I could welcome into my lexicon.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest *wholesome*.

Conducive to or indicative of good health or well-being.

There are a lot of examples for *wholesome food*.

Origin: from whole (healthy) + -some. [(TFD)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wholesome)

Answer (score 6):

[thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/health%20food) also has entries for "health food", but as Hot Licks points out in the comments, they are all more specific: "low fat food", "low calorie", "natural food".

If you want more generic terms, I suggest using adjectives like "balanced", "optimal", "healthy" with nouns like "diet", "food", "nutrition" to create alternative two-word phrases.

Answer (score 5):

In colloquial usage "healthy food" is fine but it's not correct.  that's why you are getting such odd results in your thesaurus search.  "Healthy" describes the state of living things.  "A healthy person should be able to run a mile in under 9 minutes".   As others have pointed out, "Healthful"  (and "wholesome" "nutritious" and others) is the word for food.

A person became healthy by exercising and eating healthful foods.

Comment: Would you use "healthy" in the context of healthy eating? (ex. sentence: Healthy eating has many benefits.)

Comment: Historically, "healthy" was not an adverb.  Quite common and no one would think twice about it, but healthy eating is not strictly correct.  Modern usage has blurred the distinction.  Good discussion here:  https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/04/healthy-healthily.html

Answer (score 5):

I think both of the top answers are correct, however I would like to highlight a semantic difference between the two.

I think if you mean "good" in the moral sense, then "wholesome" but if you mean "good" in the scientific/biological sense then "nutritious".

I wouldn't ever call [Soylent](https://www.soylent.com) "wholesome" but I would say it's "nutritious". Whereas home made deep fried battered fish might not be the most "nutritious" it is "wholesome".